# Set timezone for sudo'ed commands

Tags: sudo, time-zone

When running as a user, I like to have times printed relative to myself, so I have the TZ environment variable set. But then for example "sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart" causes nginx to be run in my local timezone instead of UTC, and having the various daemons disagree about timezone causes lots of subtle problems (for example fail2ban will think that all bans have already expired)

How do I get sudo to ignore just that environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

/etc/sudoers.d/tz

```
Defaults env_keep -= "TZ"
```

Comment: perhaps using some verbs would make your answer a little more clear